# How To Display Featured Posts From Multiple Blogs in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, blogs, posts, shopify-template

I have multiple blogs on my Shopify site. I'm trying to display posts from ALL blogs on the site in the featured section on the homepage. However, when I attempt to select them in the admin area, it only allows me to select one at a time.

What do I need to put in the `{% schema %}` (or template code) to allow me to select more than one blog in the theme's admin area, thus displaying posts from more than one blog in featured section in the template?

[image]

Here is my current `{% schema %}`:

```
{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Blog posts",
  "class": "index-section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Heading",
      "default": "Blog posts"
    },
    {
      "id": "blog",
      "type": "blog",
      "label": "Blog"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "post_limit",
      "label": "Posts",
      "min": 3,
      "max": 12,
      "step": 3,
      "default": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "blog_show_author",
      "label": "Show author",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "blog_show_date",
      "label": "Show date",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_view_all",
      "label": "Show 'View all' button",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Blog posts",
      "category": "Blog",
      "settings": {
        "blog": "News",
        "post_limit": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the simplest of Liquid constructions like:

```html
{% for blog in blogs %}
  <p>I am blog {{ blog.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

That kind of thing? If you have many blogs, I would start with that. If you cannot iterate your existing blogs, you have no hope of showing off their contents in a section of your store, whatever that may be.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already have the blogs showing up in the template via `{%- if blog.articles_count > 0 -%}`. My issue is with the choosing of the blogs in the admin, specially for the featured post section. It only allows me to choose one, and I'd like to choose multiple.

Comment: Your question is better asked as "My theme is limited to one blog post selected for blah". At the same time, you have to understand that that weakness in your theme is fixed by using Liquid as I pointed out to you. You can do anything with Liquid and your blogs, regardless of the limits in your theme code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? Just add some more block schema

```
    
<div class = "blog-container">

    {% if section.settings.blog != blank %}
    {% for blog in section.settings.blog %}
     
     <p>{{blog.title}}</p>

    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}

{% if section.settings.blogone != blank %}
 {% for blog in section.settings.blogone %}
     
     <p>{{blog.title}}</p>

{% endfor %}

{% endif %}


{% if section.settings.blogtwo != blank %}
 {% for blog in section.settings.blogtwo %}
     
     <p>{{blog.title}}</p>

  {% endfor %}
{% endif % }
     </div> 

 {% schema %}
{
  "name": "Blog posts",
  "class": "index-section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Heading",
      "default": "Blog posts"
    },
    {
      "id": "blog",
      "type": "blog",
      "label": "Blog"
    },
 {
      "id": "blogtwo",
      "type": "blog",
      "label": "Blog Two"
    },
 {
      "id": "blogthree",
      "type": "blog",
      "label": "Blog Three"
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "post_limit",
      "label": "Posts",
      "min": 3,
      "max": 12,
      "step": 3,
      "default": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "blog_show_author",
      "label": "Show author",
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "blog_show_date",
      "label": "Show date",
      "default": true
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_view_all",
      "label": "Show 'View all' button",
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Blog posts",
      "category": "Blog",
      "settings": {
        "blog": "News",
        "post_limit": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```